# Show complete target name in ingress mobile client

Tags: ingress

Is there a way/view to see the full name of a target with the mobile app?  Longer names seem to get truncated. My main interest is more sightseeing related than game play.  I'd like to get to know my newly adopted hometown a bit better.

Answer (score 5):

You can have more informations about portals by clicking on the photo (there is a little `i`), this will lead you to the information's screen of the portal with :

- complete name
- bigger photo
- detailled description
- for the latest submissions the name (and the faction) of the submitter.

If the name or description isn't fully readable, click on the warning symbol (top right) to edit name or description, then you'll be able to see the complete name :-) .

Comment: That doesn't work. One you can deduce says Shakespeare Museum of Philad...becomes Shakespeare Museu..f Philad after pressing the I button. No way I can determine to see the full name.

Comment: @shemathings I edited my answer with a kind of solution :-)

Comment: Ok its a hack but fulfills the stated goal. +1

Comment: Upgrade portal actually shows the most info.